# Carrierwave + ActiveAdmin with example for file and image field. results in "stack level too deep"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am attempting to create a file and image field on ActiveAdmin.  Example.

[image: Active Admin example]

> What I have so far.

- Created a Migration to add file and image columns to the database.
- Created Active Admin and edited display form.
- Created the model
- Created 2 uploaders

My code results in "stack level too deep" error.

The weird thing is the code is exactly the same as my example which works fine.

**admin/product.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  permit_params :title, :image, :file

form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
   f.inputs "Create Product..." do
     f.input :title
     f.input :image, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb))
     f.input :file, :as => :file

   end
     f.actions
 end
end
```

**models/product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :file, FileProductsUploader
    mount_uploader :image, ImageProductsUploader
end
```

**uploaders/file_products_uploader.rb**

```
 class FileProductsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file

 def store_dir
   "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end
end
```

**uploaders/image_products_uploader.rb**

```
  class ImageProductsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
   storage :file

  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fit => [250, 250]
  end
end
```

> **Error Message**

```
 SystemStackError in Admin::ProductsController#update

 stack level too deep

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ViiAmqH+S9XjP0wBSc7I2USEl1LXLw/N532Kd+uhNqc=",
 "product"=>{"title"=>"First Product",
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x50e6008 @tempfile=#   <Tempfile:C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20141016-7388-e5v6is>,
 @original_filename="example.png", 
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[image]\";  filename=\"example.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">},
"commit"=>"Update Product", 
"id"=>"1"}
```

**Console Error message**

```
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, commit, id
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 138ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:79
```

Comment: you have permitted parameters in both admin and products model remove the `product_params` method in your model and try once

Comment: The permitted parameters are now only defined in admin, but the stack level too deep error still remains.

Comment: can you add your stack error trace here

Comment: Question has now been updated with the error message.

Comment: If I comment out "process :resize_to_fit => [250, 250]" on the uploader it saves without the error, so the issue might be with Rmagic on windows.

Comment: Found this https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1330 . Adding gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick' did not solve the issue for me though

Comment: try to include this `  include CarrierWave::RMagick` in fileuploader file also

Comment: @anusha I can see the preview of the uploaded image using  `f.input :image, as: :file,  hint: f.template.image_tag(f.object.image_url)` but some junk text are displaying on the edit form like `#<#<Class:0x007f90d83502a8>:0x007f90e37d5430>` how I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the online solutions worked for me. I solved the error changing the local temp directory

**Uploader/***

```
def cache_dir
   # should return path to cache dir
   Rails.root.join 'tmp/uploads'
end
```